# PHP combine multiple arrays into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

I am writing code in PHP to collect all the hashtags which I've used in all my media posts and see in how many posts I've used the hashtag and how many likes the post with that hashtag received in total.

I have collected all of the media posts in my database and are now able to export this information. Here is an example of the multidimensional array which is being output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [caption] => #londra #london #london_only #toplondonphoto #visitlondon #timeoutlondon #londres #london4all #thisislondon #mysecretlondon #awesomepix #passionpassport #shootermag #discoverearth #moodygrams #agameoftones #neverstopexploring #beautifuldestinations #artofvisuals #roamtheplanet #jaw_dropping_shots #fantastic_earth #visualsoflife #bdteam #nakedplanet #ourplanetdaily #earthfocus #awesome_earthpix #exploretocreate #londoneye
            [likesCount] => 522
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [caption] => #londra #london #london_only #toplondonphoto #visitlondon #timeoutlondon #londres #london4all #thisislondon #mysecretlondon #awesomepix #passionpassport #shootermag #discoverearth #moodygrams #agameoftones #neverstopexploring #beautifuldestinations #artofvisuals #roamtheplanet #jaw_dropping_shots #fantastic_earth #visualsoflife #bdteam #nakedplanet #ourplanetdaily #earthfocus #awesome_earthpix #harrods #LDN4ALL_One4All
            [likesCount] => 1412
        )
)
```

I am able to separate these hashtags out using the following function:

```
function getHashtags($string) {  
    $hashtags= FALSE;  
    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/u", $string, $matches);  
    if ($matches) {
        $hashtagsArray = array_count_values($matches[0]);
        $hashtags = array_keys($hashtagsArray);
    }
    return $hashtags;
}
```

Now I want to create a multidimensional array for each hashtag which should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [hash] => #londra
        [times_used] => 2
        [total_likes] => 153
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [hash] => #london
        [times_used] => 12
        [total_likes] => 195
    )
)
```

I am quite new to this and not sure how to achieve this. Help and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: How do you calculate the likes count for each hashtag?

Comment: It's hard to calculate it, but I would sum up the total likes in the posts which the has tag has been used in and then divide it by the amount of posts it has been used in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be  easier to use the  hashtags as keys in your  array. You can
transform it later to  your final format if you want to.  The idea is to
traverse your input  array and within each element iterate  on the given
hashtags string, increasing counters.

And if  your hashtags  are always  in a string  like that,  separated by
whitespace,  you can  also  get an  array of  then  with `explode()`  or
`preg_split()` for finer control.

```
$posts = # your input array
$tags = [];

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $hashtags = explode(' ', $post['caption']);
    foreach ($hashtags as $tag) {
        if (!key_exists($tag, $tags)) {
            # first time seeing this one, initialize an entry
            $tags[$tag]['counter'] = 0;
            $tags[$tag]['likes'] = 0;
        }
        $tags[$tag]['counter']++;
        $tags[$tag]['likes'] += $post['likesCount'];
    }
}
```

Transforming to something closer to your original request:

```
$result = array_map(function($hashtag, $data) {
    return [
        'hash' => $hashtag,
        'times_used' => $data['counter'],
        'total_likes' => $data['likes'],
        'average_likes' => $data['likes'] / $data['counter'],
    ];
}, array_keys($tags), $tags);
```